# Argument index specifier not working on MinGW gcc

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, format-specifiers

I can't get the argument index format specifier on `fprintf()` to work when compiling C code on Windows with **gcc-7.2.0-mingw**.

---

Take the following program as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;

    x = 10;
    fprintf(stdout, "%1$d == %1$d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Let's compile and run it:

```
C:\path\to\dir>gcc -Wall -std=c89 -o main.exe main.c

C:\path\to\dir>main.exe
$d == $d

C:\path\to\dir>
```

While I expected the output to be `10 == 10` <sup>([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw46LKzOvRCE3MTNPoyw/M0VToZpLAQhAghXWXGB2hYKtgqGBNZidVlAElErTAGrPLy3RUVBSNVRJUbC1VQDRMXlKOgoVmlBtRaklpUV5CkCNtf//AwA))</sup>.

What's happening and how can I make the argument index specifier work properly?

---

<sub>**Note:** the same happens if I try to print strings, floats or anything else.</sub>

Comment: I think you may be out of luck.  See http://www.mingw.org/wiki/C99.

Comment: If you need this functionality, your best bet may be to bring along your own `sprintf` implementation (acquired from elsewhere) that supports `%n$` and `sprintf()` into the strings where you need to use this, then `puts()` the completed string.

Comment: That's so disappointing... Thank you @eddiem for the clarification.